# angular universal working successfully on localhost not on production server

Tags: angular, nginx, angular-universal

angular universal running successfully on localhost but when deployed to production with nginx page view source only showing the static contents, but the same code is working in localhost.

I have also tested by disabling the js of browser, localhost is running as expected but when deployed to production server again only the static components gets rendered.

Please help.

```
// These are important and needed before anything else
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

// Faster server renders w/ Prod mode (dev mode never needed)
enableProdMode();

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const { AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = require('./dist/server/main.bundle');

// Express Engine
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
// Import module map for lazy loading
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser'));

// TODO: implement data requests securely
app.get('/api/*', (req, res) => {
  res.status(404).send('data requests are not supported');
});

// Server static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser')));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'browser', 'index.html'), { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: Do you see any error in the browser's debugging console?

Comment: I got it working, actually cloudflare was messing with things.

Answer (score 2):

There is an article about [server-side rendering](https://codeburst.io/angular-server-side-rendering-using-angular-cli-bbde0c0eefe9) which is helpful to read, and I also highly recommend you to take a look at Angular [Universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) repository on Git.

Please follow these steps and let me know if it does not work yet:

1. Build the server project app.
2. Run it on your localhost. *Does it work?*
3. Depends on your build, and WebPack settings you might need to upload `node_modules` directory as well. Some WebPack settings (like [Universal-starters](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter)) lets you deploy just `dist` directory and `node_modules` won't be needed.
4. When you deployed the code on your server, you need to run your node app. You can run it using `node dist/server.js`, or using one of Nodejs production process manager, such as [`pm2`](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) or [`forever`](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever).
5. You need to configure Nginx to redirect to the defined Nodejs port (`4000` or what you exported)

It hopefully works correctly if you follow the instructions above.

Comment: I have used the same procedure to build the server and browser module. I have also deployed the project on digital ocean with nginx as proxy server for node. I am using pm2. everything works fine except the fact that page view source only returning the static elements and not the ones which gets rendered after the api calls. also I have created the same setup on my local system and it works but I don't know why it is not working on server.

Comment: Are you sure you don't check if platform is only browser?

Comment: the issue was related to cloudflare, npw it is working fine.

Comment: @PijushKarmakar I'm glad you could solve the problem yourself! Thanks for letting me know

Comment: @PijushKarmakar Please let us know, what did you changed in cloudflare settings ? Somehow, i am facing the same issue.

Comment: I tried switching off js caching, js rewrite but the response was same, so I ended up removing cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue. On localhost the response for the initial page prints the route's source in DevTools, but not on production. Turns out it was version mismatch on all the @angular packages on localhost vs production.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same issue where localhost worked but prod on server didn't. Turns out it's due to the http protocol. On localhost it's http and server it's https, and this caused some asset requests to fail.